# How to get environmental variables in MainApplication.java react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, environment-variables

I have created process.env.key file and i want this variable in MainApplication.java and strings.xml file

Can you please help me how to get variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a long time trying to do the same thing, I finally win using a react native library with native integration for environment variables: `react-native-config`

*I recommend you to read the README.md file with the most updated installation and use steps, but, I will put here the exact steps that I did to can do it.
https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config#native-usage*

**SOLUTION STEPS**

1. First install the `react-native-config` library:

```sh
yarn add react-native-config
react-native link react-native-config
```

2. Add inside your `MainApplication.java` file this code where you need to use the environment var:

```java
// example, here I added the code inside onCreate() method of my MainApplication class
public void onCreate() {
    String VAR_WITH_ANY_NAME = BuildConfig.ANY_ENV_VAR_AS_YOU_WANT;
   // ... any code ...
  }
```

*(I think you had created your .env file with the needed variables)*

3. Now, rebuild your project (I like to do it in different terminals, one for the bundle and another for build)

   - Init your js bundle with `yarn && yarn start --reset-cache` in a terminal.
   - Recompile your native project with `yarn run android` in another terminal.